# How can I add a fade animation to dynamically changing text using pure JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a heading of text on a webpage that is sequentially, dynamically, and randomly modified on timed intervals. Currently, I'm changing each word in the text using the `textContent` method, which results in a clunky animation. I'd like to add a fade-in/out animation to the text for each word/phrase change. I know something similar can be done with jQuery, but I'd like to see if it can be accomplished in pure JavaScript with CSS if it can be added onto my existing code. If I have to change my entire approach (like putting all the text into HTML elements and using CSS to display each one) that's fine as well, as long as it's efficient.

Here is my code.

```js
// Text to replace elements in h1 with
const languages = [
  ['Bienvenidos', 'a', 'odio la escuela'],
  ['Willkomen', 'zu', 'ich hasse schule'],
  ['欢迎', '来到', '我讨厌上学']
]

// Shuffles the array of languages (occurs once the array has been iterated through entirely)
const shuffle = () => {
  for (let i = languages.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    const temp = languages[i]
    languages[i] = languages[j]
    languages[j] = temp
  }
}

// DOM elements to be modified
const welcomeTitle = document.getElementById('welcome-landing-header')
const toTitle      = document.getElementById('to-landing-header')
const landingTitle = document.getElementById('landing-title')

// Function to modify the text
let languageIndex = 0
const changeHeading = () => {
  /* Case where the language index has gone out of bounds of the array; reshuffle array and 
     reset text */
  if (languageIndex === languages.length) {
    languageIndex = 0
    shuffle()
    welcomeTitle.textContent = 'Welcome'
    setTimeout(() => toTitle.textContent = 'to', 1000)
    setTimeout(() => landingTitle.textContent = 'i hate school', 2000)
  } else {
    // Iterate through the random language selected, changing each DOM element sequentially
    const language = languages[languageIndex]
    welcomeTitle.textContent = language[0]
    setTimeout(() => toTitle.textContent = language[1], 1000)
    setTimeout(() => landingTitle.textContent = language[2], 2000)
    languageIndex++
  }
}

setInterval(changeHeading, 3000)
```

```html
<h1>
  <span id="welcome-landing-header">Welcome</span>
  <span id="to-landing-header">to</span>
  <br>
  <span id="landing-title">i hate school</span>
</h1>
```

I just want to add a fade in/out animation to each `span` element that is modified, instead of the text changing without any animation as it is currently. It's tough because there are 3 staggered animations happening at once (one for 'Welcome', one for 'to', and one for 'i hate school'). If anyone could help me out or provide a more efficient solution, I'd really appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [W3.CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_animate.asp) Animations and add a new js function to create what you want. So that your code will finally look something like the following lines

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .fade {
            animation: myanimation 1.5s;
        }
        @keyframes myanimation {
            from {opacity: 0;}
            to {opacity: 1;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <span id="welcome-landing-header" class="fade">Welcome</span>
        <span id="to-landing-header" class="fade">to</span>
        <br>
        <span id="landing-title" class="fade">i hate school</span>
    </h1>
    <script>
        // Text to replace elements in h1 with
        const languages = [
            ['Bienvenidos', 'a', 'odio la escuela'],
            ['Willkomen', 'zu', 'ich hasse schule'],
            ['欢迎', '来到', '我讨厌上学']
        ]

        // Shuffles the array of languages (occurs once the array has been iterated through entirely)
        const shuffle = () => {
            for (let i = languages.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
                const temp = languages[i]
                languages[i] = languages[j]
                languages[j] = temp
            }
        }

        // DOM elements to be modified
        const welcomeTitle = document.getElementById('welcome-landing-header')
        const toTitle      = document.getElementById('to-landing-header')
        const landingTitle = document.getElementById('landing-title')

        // Function to modify the text
        let languageIndex = 0
        const changeHeading = () => {
            /* Case where the language index has gone out of bounds of the array; reshuffle array and
               reset text */
            if (languageIndex === languages.length) {
                languageIndex = 0
                shuffle()
                welcomeTitle.textContent = 'Welcome'
                setTimeout(() => toTitle.textContent = 'to', 1000)
                setTimeout(() => landingTitle.textContent = 'i hate school', 2000)
            } else {

                // Iterate through the random language selected, changing each DOM element sequentially
                const language = languages[languageIndex]
                welcomeTitle.textContent = language[0]
                setTimeout(() => toTitle.textContent = language[1], 1000)
                setTimeout(() => landingTitle.textContent = language[2], 2000)
                languageIndex++
            }
        }

        const fadeAnimation = () => {
            const welcomeTitle = document.getElementById('welcome-landing-header')
            const toTitle      = document.getElementById('to-landing-header')
            const landingTitle = document.getElementById('landing-title')

            welcomeTitle.className = '';
            toTitle.className = '';
            landingTitle.className = '';

            setTimeout(() => welcomeTitle.className = 'fade', 10)
            setTimeout(() => toTitle.className = 'fade', 1000)
            setTimeout(() => landingTitle.className = 'fade', 2000)
        }

        setInterval(changeHeading, 3000)
        setInterval(fadeAnimation, 3000)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works well, thank you! However, I didn't want to use W3.CSS since their opacity animation is fixed at 0.8 seconds, i.e., you're unable to modify the animation length. Is there any way I can change the animation length to longer than 0.8 seconds or use another method?

Comment: So you can use custom css style and make fade animation. I edited my answer. You can change animation duration in css styles.